# how to stop my webkit frame animation?

Tags: webkit

i am doing a small animation using webkit animation property. it's working finally, it is back to the first step. that mean i am moving the object into 200px, once that reach 200px, it should stay, should not come back to old state. how can i stop in to the final state?

my css code :

```
 .box {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background-color: black;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
            -webkit-animation-delay:5s;

            position:absolute;
        }


        @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
            from {
              left: 0px;
            }
            to {
              left: 200px;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

webkit animated properties return to their original values when the animation completes.
(see http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Animations/Animations.html)

you'll want to capture the end event of the animation with a listener and set the 'left' property of the box to 200px (your ending point).

something like (uses jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',function( event ) { $('.box').css('left', '200px'); }, false);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If one-way animation is what you want I think you should use [Webkit Transitions](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transitions/Transitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH4-SW1).

Comment: Transitions play only once and remain at the end position unless explicitly reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;