# webkit animation play state: how to start/stop animation on demand with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm working on a game and just found out about -webkit-animation-play-state CSS attribute. I want certain text to show itself as a short animation, then hide and show when called again (in javascript).

I figured out how to start animation when I want to in javascript, but after its finished, the text stays on the screen, which I don't want to.

HTML:

```
<p id="INFO">
    TEST
</p>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   from {
     opacity: 0.0;
     font-size: 100%;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1.0;
     font-size: 400%;
   }
}

#INFO {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 200px;
 -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var INFO = document.getElementById("INFO");
INFO.innerHTML = "WRONG";
INFO.style.color = "RED";
INFO.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
INFO.style.visibility = "visible";
```

I read some questions/answers about -webkit-animation-play-state on this site, but none regarding the issue I am having. 
One thing I read about was that animation goes to its default values when its ended. But my default values say that animation is "hidden" ? source: [how to stop my webkit frame animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126628/how-to-stop-my-webkit-frame-animation)

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.
If I was not clear enough, ask for more info please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, you don't need to use -webkit-animation-play-state.

Instead, try starting the animation by applying a class with the animation properties set. Then use a JavaScript event listener to remove the class once the animation finishes.

You should also keep the element hidden with `opacity` instead of `visibility:hidden` since you are manipulating the `opacity` in the animation.

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
   from {
     opacity: 0.0;
     font-size: 100%;
   }
   to {
     opacity: 1.0;
     font-size: 400%;
   }
}

#INFO {
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 200px;
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
var INFO = document.getElementById("INFO");
INFO.innerHTML = "WRONG";
INFO.style.color = "RED";

INFO.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (e) {
  this.classList.remove('pulse');
});
```

DEMO >> [CodePen](http://codepen.io/vivekvasani/pen/dIojz)

Comment: this demo doesn't do anything for me unfortunately, what could go wrong?

Comment: That worked for me in my environment, thank you :) Didn't work in demo example though :)